# ¿Cómo obtener en nombre de una imagen desde el path recibido desde un input?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estoy haciendo un upload de un imagen, y luego guardar el nombre de imagen en DDBB y la imagen fisicamenete en una carpeta del proyecto.  Chrome funciona Todo bien -Chrome solo selecciona el nombre del imagen- pero en microsoft Edge lo que hace es seleccionar toda la ruta local de la imagen. 
En el código tengo lo siguiente:

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["image"];
```

Al hora de ententar  obtener el nombre de `file`, `file.FileName`. El resultado es toda la ruta local del imagen.

Cómo podría resolverlo??
Gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera medalla. También es interesante leer [ask] para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta.Cual es tu problema? Extraer el nombre de la imagen del path que recibes? Puedes poner un ejemplo?

Comment: Sí, exactamente. Extraer el nombre de la imagen del  Path que obtengo desde el input, Además ¿por qué en Chrome funciona y Edge no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para extraer el nombre de archivo de una ruta, puedes hacer uso del método [`GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) del espacio de nombres `Path`. En tu caso sería algo asi:

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["image"];
string filename=Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
```

No debes preocuparte de si en `file.FileName` ya tienes el nombre del archivo. `Path.GetFileName` te devolvera en ese caso el mismo archivo.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Pikoh! Solucionado!!